# Помогите понять в чем проблема с функцией

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели

Oшибка: `invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive] Function1(*A,x,k)`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Function1(int *A, int x, int k)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {  
        *A++;

        if (*A == x)
        {
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int k;
    int x = 15;
    int Arr[6] = {0, 15, 15, 35, 15, 20};
    int *A = Arr;

    Function1(*A, x, k);

    cout << k << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Если что, задача состоит в том, что бы через функцию сделать перебор массива на наличие совпадения с числом, и вывести на экран количество совпадений.Используя при этом указатель на массив.

Comment: Компилятор вам ясно сказал, в чем проблема. Что вы хотели сказать этим `*A` в вызове функции?

Comment: да и строчка `*A++;`  в цикле выглядит сомнительно...

Comment: Прибавления имеет очень высокий приоритет, и вы изменяете указатель. `*(A++)`. Зачем тогда пишете звёздочку, если не используете значение? Можно просто менять указатель как `++A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int *A` в декларации означает: "A это указатель на int"

У вас есть переменная `A`,тип ее - `int *`. В ней хранится какой-то адрес.

Выражение `A` это адрес,  или указатель. Оно подходит для типа аргумента функции, которую вы вызываете.

Выражение `*A` это само значение, которое лежит в памяти по этому адресу.

Функция требует не значение, а адрес, а вы пытаетесь передать в нее значение. В данном случае - значение первого элемента массива, то есть 0.

Система типов C++ не позволяет вам этого сделать, было бы ошибкой интерпретировать целочисленное значение как адрес.

Comment: Я Вас понял, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать что бы было правильно? Буду очень признателен.

Comment: 'Function1(*A,x,k)' замените на 'Function1(A,x,k)'